# How to use the duplicate brush in Krita

Tags: brush, krita

How do you use the duplicate brush in Krita.
I've got an X but can't seem to get further.
The manual is not very comprehensive.

Comment: Wow, never even heard of that app before. You might try here: http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=139&t=117152&p=290484&hilit=How+to+duplicate+brush#p290484

Comment: Thanks Scott.  I've been using Photoshop for years.
Krita seems a fantastic App, but does seem to be lacking in reading materials at the moment!

Comment: @ChrisNevill In the newest Krita it's now called the "Clone Brush" - documentation is in the user manual here: https://docs.krita.org/Clone

Comment: Thanks Billy - glad to here Krita is still progressing.  I've not used it for a while now.  Might have to pick it up again at some point!

Answer (score 8):

For me this way worked:

1. Select Duplicate Brush from Brushes drop down (Tool button Underneath the Tools Menu)
2. You may get an X or you may get a colour dropper icon.
3. Press the Ctrl button to choose the place you want to duplicate from
4. Now you can brush in the duplicate area.