# How to set source for Krita clone brush on tablet? (no keyboard)

Tags: brush, krita, digital

Trying to use the Clone Brush tool in Krita, but am unable to set the source for pasting from. The answer [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/124753/how-do-i-use-the-duplicate-brush-in-krita-on-a-tablet) specifies the default keyboard shortcut `Ctrl`+`Alt`+click for changing the source. Not having a keyboard on my tablet, this doesn't work for me. I've checked the Clone Brush settings, but can't find anything to move the source point the "long" way.

Running Krita 4.4.3 on a Samsung Tab S7+.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe someone here can give you the answer, but I got a feeling there aren't too many Krita users here, at least ones who have used it on a tablet. I think [forum](https://krita-artists.org/) or possibly [subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/krita/) would give you better answers.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The Krita for Android app is in beta, so it may not be fully functional yet. Maybe contact the developer. I've never used it except on a PC.  My answer you linked to is for using Krita on a computer, not on an Android tablet.

Comment: Note: On the [apkpure site](https://apkpure.com/krita/org.krita) as far as the latest beta is concerned, it says "Some issues have been fixed, but Krita on ChromeOS/Android is not ready for production". In the meantime I'd advise you to try Krita on a PC/Linux/Mac instead. Perhaps get yourself a cheap graphics tablet to attach to your computer.

Comment: If it's not mobile ready, I'd rather just try something else: https://www.makeuseof.com/best-procreate-alternatives-android/